# Using CSV Sniffer to determine a delimiter but doesnt work on multiple files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using the Sniffer class in CSV Reader to determine what a delimiter is in a CSV file and it works on single files but if I add in a loop and point it to a folder with the same CSV in, it throws out this error:

```
File "delimiter.py", line 17, in read_csv_delimit
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string
```

The script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import csv
import os

def read_csv_delimit(file_dir, csv_file):
    # Initialise list
    file_csv = []
    # Open csv & check delimiter
    with open(file_dir + "/" + csv_file, newline='', encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as csvfile:
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
        csvfile.seek(0)
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
        for item in reader:
            file_csv.append(item[0])
        #del file_csv[0]
        return file_csv

def split_path(full_path):
    #path = path.rstrip(os.sep)
    head, tail = os.path.split(full_path)
    return (head, tail)


machine_dir = input("Drop the folder here: ")

# Get list of machine csv
machines = os.listdir(machine_dir)

for machine in machines:
    print(machine)
    #file_dir, csv_file = split_path(csv_file)
    machine_list = read_csv_delimit(machine_dir, machine)
    print(machine_list)
```

Comment: What does `print("'{}'".format(dialect.delmiter))` placed before `reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)` outputs?

Comment: `.DS_Store

''

Traceback (most recent call last):
delimiter.py", line 15, in read_csv_delimit
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string`

The script is picking up all files and not just csv's, isn't it? So a .DS_Store is whats messing it up.

How do I add a constraint so it reads only .csv file types (or excludes dotted files)?

Weird, as I cant see any hidden files in the folder.

Comment: If the given answer solves the issue consider accepting it or please add the solution as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the trace, it seems that your script does pick non-CSV files, indeed. You can use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module for fine-tuning the search pattern to pick up only the files you want, but even a simple extension lookup should suffice:

```
target = input("Drop the folder here: ")

machine_list = [read_csv_delimit(target, m) for m in os.listdir(target) if m[-4:] == ".csv"]
print(machine_list)
```

Checking for the entered directory validity, tho, is highly recommended, even if it's performed with the simplest `os.path.isdir(target)`.

I'd also recommend you to use [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) facilities to build up your path in the `read_csv_delimit()` function, e.g.:

```
with open(os.path.join(file_dir, csv_file), newline='', encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as csvfile:
```